# Integrate-Function R: Error in match.fun(f)

Tags: r, match, integrate

Users,

when trying to compute the Kullback-Leibler-Divergence i encountered a problem with the integrate-function of R; for the formula i tried to reproduce see here: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/526682a951093613fe4c721db57b68ec991bdf07

instead of "p(x)" and "q(x)" i used "f.1" and "f.2", respectively.

Here is the code:

```
f.1 = function(x){
    dis.t = dt(x,df.1)
    return(dis.t)
    }
  f.2 = function(x){
    dis.norm = (1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma.sq))*exp(-((x-mu)^2)/2*sigma.sq)
    return(dis.norm)
    }
  test = function(x){
    kld = f.1(x)*log(f.1(x)/f.2(x))
    return(kld)

    }

  KLd = function(x){integrate(test(x),-Inf,Inf)}
```

It returns an error: "Error in match.fun(f) : 'test(x)' is not a function, character or symbol";
if i use "is.function(test)", it returns "TRUE".

I appreciate your help in identifying the problem and a solution;

additional information: The x i fed into the function was a pseudo-random t-distributed sample: 
df.1 = 3
n = 25
rt(n, df.1)

the f.2 function is just the density function of the normal distribution;

Best regards
Erin

Comment: The integrate function takes the function name (in your case test) and the limits, so here it should be integrate(test,-Inf,Inf). What is the meaning of the parameter x you are trying to pass to it? Integration of the function in this case will be done from -Inf to +Inf.

Comment: oh jeez, that was simple. Thank you very much!